# website with expired SSL

Tags: security, ssl, ssl-certificate

A website I'm trying to register at has an expired SSL certificate. I have the option to either use HTTPS with an expired certificate or HTTP, which option would be more secure? Is the expired SSL still encrypted?

The information I'll be submiting is not too important

Comment: If you trust the certificate, then HTTPS is secure, if you don't trust the certificate then you shouldn't submit anything because HTTP is **never** secure.  It is not normally possible to not use HTTPS when a website configured to use a SSL certificate.  How do you plan on forcing the website NOT to use the certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP has no security at all.
HTTPS is at least encrypted, expired or not.

When visitors come to a website with an expired cert, browser like firefox and chrome display a warning.  The user then has to click a few things (like Advanced and Proceed anyway) to override this block.  In some cases the browser may completely block access to sites with defective security,

Using "[lets encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)", a global group promoting encryption to get a new free cert would be even better.

Comment: @techraf I reworded it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sessions are always encrypted when using https, regardless of the status of the certificate.

However, if the certificate is expired, you cannot be confident that the server you are talking to is the one you intend.  This is another part of the https contract - that (provided everything has been done correctly) you can trust that the server is who it says it is, if it presents a certificate that matches the name of the server you are going to.

This trust is established by you trusting certificate authorities (CA) that have confirmed the identity of the server (there are different levels of certificate that can be considered increasing levels of trust).

A CA will say that a server certificate can be trusted for a period of time, after which, you should no longer trust it.

If the data is "no too important" consider what the impact would be if the server you are communicating with is not the one you expect.